# How Can I re-size an image in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need it so that in my code if something evaluates to true it changes the image location and size.

This is my code so far:

```
With picValueTwentySix
   .Location = New Point(302, 134)
   .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(169, 40)
   .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
End With
```

Anybody know why it isn't re-sizing?

Thanks!

Comment: changing the size/location of a picturebox does nothing to the image

Comment: I don't see you doing anything here with an actual image.  Try this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone has already mentioned, you need to work the the image.  Here is a function I made up for ease of use.

```
Public Function ResizeImage(ByVal image As Image, ByVal size As Size, Optional ByVal preserveAspectRatio As Boolean = True) As Image
    Try
        Dim newWidth As Integer
        Dim newHeight As Integer
        If preserveAspectRatio Then
            Dim originalWidth As Integer = image.Width
            Dim originalHeight As Integer = image.Height
            Dim percentWidth As Single = CSng(size.Width) / CSng(originalWidth)
            Dim percentHeight As Single = CSng(size.Height) / CSng(originalHeight)
            Dim percent As Single = IIf(percentHeight < percentWidth, percentHeight, percentWidth)
            newWidth = CInt(originalWidth * percent)
            newHeight = CInt(originalHeight * percent)
        Else
            newWidth = size.Width
            newHeight = size.Height
        End If

        Dim newImage As Image = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        Using graphicsHandle As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        End Using

        Return newImage

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return image
    End Try
End Function
```

Basically it creates a new blank graphic to the dimensions you request, then copies the original image to it while scaling it to fit.  I think if you step throw it a line at a time you should be pretty self explanatory, but ask if you have questions...

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer!  I'll try it out in a bit and let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: Remember to click accept on any answer you end up going with.  Also upvote any answer that you feel was helpful.  Not in just this question but all you read as well.  This helps future folks with the same question find good answers....

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Plutonix, changing the Picturebox size will not affect the image size itself, you have to make sure the actual image size is bigger than the size of the picture box, set the **size mode** of the picturebox to **stretchimage**, in this case once you resize the picture box the change will reflect. Also refresh the picture box after resizing.